# How do I overwrite the particular webform submit event in template.php?

Tags: 7, webforms

I want to control a particular webform submission event, and I am trying to use the following function in my template.php file.

```
function bartik_form_webform_client_form_7_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {}
```

The function is not working. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7). This will help you to alter the array of the submission handlers and add a new submission handler.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'Your-Webform-ID') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_settings_form_submit';
  }
}

function custom_settings_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Your code here.
}
```